# Shopware 6 : Check globally if customer is connected

Tags: twig, shopware, shopware6

How to check globally if customer is logged in in all template of Shopware 6 (not for a specific route) ?
I want to check this variable using template twig.

Comment: Do you mean "logged in"?

Comment: Yeah ! I mean "logged in". Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following if-statement in any template to check whether a customer is currently logged-in:

```
{% if context.customer is defined %}
    customer is logged in
{% endif %}
```